# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/drive/My'

Tags: google-colaboratory

Have u guys ever got this error?

I'm using the GoogleColab for my tiny project.
For my project, I re-installed keras 2.1.5 & tensorflow 1.4
Even didn't forget to restart runtime.

Here is the error code:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py in open(fp, mode)
   [2808]     if filename: 
-> [2809]         fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
   [2810]         exclusive_fp = True
   [2811]

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/drive/My'
```

I have a folder named '/content/drive/My Drive/Folder/Folder' (Yes, there is a 'space' between 'My' and 'Drive') . I think it is kinda bug or sth, isn't it? I tried to fix that folder name as 'My_Drive' or 'MyDrive', but Google didn't accept to fix the name.

Or is there any solution? Please help me.

+)

Here the whole code: (basically it came from yolov3-to-kerashttps://github.com/qqwweee/keras-yolo3.git)

```
!pip install q keras==2.2.4
%tensorflow_version 1.x

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive/')

cd 'drive/My Drive'


...same as train.py...

def _main():
        annotation_path = 'train_all.txt'
        log_dir = 'logs/000/'
        classes_path = 'classes.txt'
        anchors_path = 'model_data/tiny_yolo_anchors.txt'
        class_names = get_classes(classes_path)
        num_classes = len(class_names)
        anchors = get_anchors(anchors_path)'

...same as 'train.py'...

_main()
```

and I also tried to copy the path and use it, didn't work.
either add '\' between them, didn't work.

It's driving me crazy HA!

Answer (score 0):

See line 38 of yolo3/utils.py.

```
line = annotation_line.split()
```

This is the cause of the error.

Try replacing it with the following:

```
import re
line = re.findall(r'(.+?)(\s+(\d+,\d+,\d+,\d+,\d+))+', annotation_line)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try if `'My\ Drive'` works instead of `'My Drive'`